# How to use Python's pip to download and keep the zipped files for a package?

Tags: python, download, pip, zip

If I want to use the `pip` command to download a package (and its dependencies), but *keep* all of the zipped files that get downloaded (say, django-socialregistration.tar.gz) - is there a way to do that?

I've tried various command-line options, but it always seems to unpack and *delete* the zipfile - or it gets the zipfile, but *only* for the original package, not the dependencies.

Answer (score 154, accepted):

`pip install --download` is deprecated. Starting from version 8.0.0 you should use [`pip download`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_download/) command:

```
 pip download <package-name>
```

Comment: and how to install the downloaded packages later?

Comment: This is the most up-to-date answer. Thanks

Comment: @knocte `pip install path-to-downloaded-package`

Comment: tried that some days ago and I think it still tried to retrieve deps from the internet instead of using the downloaded ones; IIRC, I had to use `sudo pip install <path-to-downloaded-package> --no-index --find-links \`pwd\``

Comment: Note that `pip download` also supports `-r requirements.txt` so you can easily download them all from an internet-connected machine then copy to an offline machine and install how the above commenters mentioned

Comment: or `pip download -d <target dir> <package>` to download to a specific directory. All dependencies are also downloaded.

Comment: Can you specify a version of the package without using `-r requirements.txt`?

Answer (score 122):

The `--download-cache` option should do what you want:

```
pip install --download-cache="/pth/to/downloaded/files" package
```

However, when I tested this, the main package downloaded, saved and installed ok, but the the dependencies were saved with their full url path as the name - a bit annoying, but all the `tar.gz` files were there.

The `--download` option downloads the main package and its dependencies and does not install any of them. (**Note** that *prior to version 1.1* the `--download` option did *not* download dependencies.)

```
pip install package --download="/pth/to/downloaded/files"
```

The `pip` documentation outlines using `--download` for [fast & local installs](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#installing-from-local-packages).

Comment: Nice, that did indeed work - although I tagged a `--no-install` option on. And you're right about the funky filenames, but at least the files are *there*.

Comment: last time I checked , `--download` option download the package **with** dependencies.

Comment: @Danial - yes, as of version 1.1, `--download` now downloads dependancies.

Comment: As of version 1.5 (possibly earlier), `pip` has a `--no-deps` option, to prevent downloading dependencies.

Comment: --download-cache is deprecated. use pip install --download <dir> <pkg>

Comment: `pip install --download` in now deprecated, and will be removed from pip 10. https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/reference/pip_download/#overview. Use `pip download somepackage`.

Comment: Specifically, the new equivalent is `pip download -d <dir> { -r requirements.txt | <packagename> }`

Comment: @rrauenza what is the `requirements.txt` for?

Comment: I think the option changed to `--cache-dir` not `--download-cache` can someone verify

Comment: Moved the checkmark from here, as the other answer is more up-to-date, sorry. Time marches on.

Answer (score 73):

I always do this to download the packages:

`pip install --download /path/to/download/to_packagename`

OR

`pip install --download=/path/to/packages/downloaded -r requirements.txt`

And when I want to install all of those libraries I just downloaded, I do this:

`pip install --no-index --find-links="/path/to/downloaded/dependencies" packagename`

OR

`pip install --no-index --find-links="/path/to/downloaded/packages" -r requirements.txt`

---

**Update**

Also, to get all the packages installed on one system, you can export them all to `requirement.txt` that will be used to intall them on another system, we do this:

`pip freeze > requirement.txt`

Then, the `requirement.txt` can be used as above for download, or do this to install them from `requirement.txt`:

`pip install -r requirement.txt`

REFERENCE: [pip installer](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/index.html)

Answer (score 16):

[`pip wheel`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_wheel/) is another option you should consider:

```
pip wheel mypackage -w .\outputdir
```

It will download packages and their dependencies to a directory (current working directory by default), but it performs the additional step of converting any source packages to wheels.

It conveniently supports requirements files:

```
pip wheel -r requirements.txt -w .\outputdir
```

Add the `--no-deps` argument if you only want the specifically requested packages:

```
pip wheel mypackage -w .\outputdir --no-deps
```

Comment: Great option when you want download and build wheels as needed at the same time

Answer (score 11):

Use **`pip download <package1 package2 package n>`** to download all the packages including dependencies

Use **`pip install --no-index --find-links . <package1 package2 package n>`** to install all the packages including dependencies. 
It gets all the files from `CWD`. 
It will not download anything

Answer (score 9):

In version 7.1.2 pip downloads the wheel of a package (if available) with the following:

```
pip install package -d /path/to/downloaded/file
```

The following downloads a source distribution:

```
pip install package -d /path/to/downloaded/file --no-binary :all:
```

These download the dependencies as well, if pip is aware of them (e.g., if `pip show package` lists them).

---

**Update**

As noted by [Anton Khodak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4454597/anton-khodak), `pip download` command is preferred since version 8. In the above examples this means that `/path/to/downloaded/file` needs to be given with option `-d`, so replacing `install` with `download` works.

Comment: I have to develop in windows and deploy on RH7 with no internet connection at all. So I download the source packages with --no-binary :all: . However this fails when Collecting django-pyodbc-azure==2.0.4.1 as this package has no source. Is there a way to download the source or if this does not exist, to download the weehl?

Answer (score 5):

## installing python packages offline

For **windows** users:

To **download** into a file
open your **cmd** and folow this:

`cd <*the file-path where you want to save it*>`

`pip download <*package name*>`

the package and the dependencies will be downloaded in the current working directory.

To **install** from the current working directory:

set your folder where you downloaded as the cwd then follow these:

`pip install <*the package name which is downloded as .whl*>  --no-index --find-links <*the file locaation where the files are downloaded*>`

this will search for dependencies in that location.

Comment: if you dont specify the platform, it will download the files for the current OS. Therefore this will not work if you install the downloaded files on other OS

Answer (score 3):

All the answers mentioned in this thread assume that the packages will be downloaded on the same OS configuration as the target OS where it has to be installed.

In my personal experience i was using windows as my work machine and had to download packages for linux environment and have seen people doing vice versa as well. I had done some extensive googling, and found [`sodim.dev`](https://sodim.dev).

All i had to do was upload requirements.txt file and select the environment configuration like OS and python version and it gives out a csv with download url, source code url etc

I guess in the backend this app spins up the OS VM as requested and installs that particular python version and then generates the report, because it does take about 15-20 minutes for 30-50 packages.

P.S.: I work in an offline environment, where security is of very high concern, and downloading packages are not that frequent. We whitelist source code and download urls for each individual requests and then after running some appsec tools, we approve/reject the source code to be downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer (RHEL) - `pip download package==version --no-deps --no-binary=:all:`