# How to save pip packages

Tags: python, django, pip

We have a python/django based web application, many components of which are installed using pip. So I would like to ask if there is a way to save or download and save the particular python packages that we are having pip install (example: pip install django==1.5.1). We would like to have in the end a collection of the packages in the versions known to be working and with which the app was developed locally. Any and all advice will be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7300321/how-to-use-pythons-pip-to-download-and-keep-the-zipped-files-for-a-package) is helpful for you.

Comment: Here's a useful question for you - will help you export project environment packages and versions into a requirements.txt file : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31684375/automatically-create-file-requirements-txt

Answer (score 19):

If I understood your question right, you can `pip freeze > requirements.txt`, this command will add all the libraries you have used/"downloaded" for your app in the file `requirements.txt`(in case it exists the file be overwritten). This command allows you to later do `pip install -r requirements.txt`. However, be aware that your Django project must be running in a virtual environment, otherwise the install command will attempt to install all the python packages in your development machine.

The `freeze` command will allow you to have the current version of the app so upon installation will attempt to install that same version. Your requirements file will look something like:

```
Flask==0.8
Jinja2==2.6
Werkzeug==0.8.3
certifi==0.0.8
chardet==1.0.1
distribute==0.6.24
gunicorn==0.14.2
requests==0.11.1
```

Your packages are installed (if using virtualenv) at: `../<your project>/<your virtual env>/<lib>/<python version>/<site-packages>/`

As for downloading you can use `pip install --download` command as @atupal suggested in his response, however think if this is really needed you can also fork those libraries on github to accomplish the same.

Here is a good source of information on how this works: http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/cookbook.html

Answer (score 10):

Maybe what you want is:

Download the packages:

```
pip install --download /path/to/download/to packagename
```

OR

```
pip install --download=/path/to/packages/downloaded -r requirements.txt
```

install all of those libraries just downloaded:

```
pip install --no-index --find-links="/path/to/downloaded/dependencies" packagename
```

OR

```
pip install --no-index --find-links="/path/to/downloaded/packages" -r requirements.txt
```

Shamelessly stolen from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7300321/how-to-use-pythons-pip-to-download-and-keep-the-zipped-files-for-a-package)

Comment: FYI, the new download equivalent is `pip download -d <dir> { -r requirements.txt | <packagename> }`

Answer (score 0):

Create a requirements.txt file.

Put:

```
django==1.5.1
```

in the first line.

Then run `pip install -r requirements.txt`

Then you can complete that file...