# Package.json in Python

Tags: python, import, module, package.json

Is there any way to have a package.json file for my python folder, like it is in NodeJS (npm) ?

For Example: if I used pip to import Flask, I want Flask to appear in the package.json file. It doesn't have to be JSON, it can be a .txt file as well.

FYI: I want the file so that I can install all the dependencies immediatelyif I transfer the files, or upload the folder into GitHub

Thanks!

Comment: read about `pip freeze` and `requirements.txt`

Comment: I don't plan to use node or npm at all. It was just an example on how npm uses package.json

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to save pip packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20623680/how-to-save-pip-packages)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can save your current state of dependencies using a requirements file. One way is to generate it using `pip freeze`:

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

You can install these requirements, again using pip:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

You can read more about it here: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#requirements-files

Comment: Important to note that pip freeze will save all packages currently installed. Not just those in use. If you aren't using an environment or not grooming your installed packages periodically the pip freeze may save unneeded packages to `requirements.txt`. There are some python packages to remedy this issue but this is an important note for the basic `pip freeze`.