# Installing packages from local source

Tags: python, linux-mint

I prefer to keep local python packages on my windows box for when im setting up a virtualenv. So I have several wheel files for various packages that I use often when creating virtualenv's, which are gotten from here:
http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

My question is on how to mimic this process in Linux Mint. Is it possible to download the packages I need (using pip? or something else?) and keep them on my machine for later use when creating a virtualenv?

And a related question, is there a way to check the dependencies that a certain package needs via the command line?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26485472/29489  provided a clean solution to use `pip wheel` to cache all your eggs/requirements and make pip (in virtualenv or not) use them automatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use

```
pip install modulename --download ~/folder_to_store_downloads
```

More here: [How to use Python's pip to download and keep the zipped files for a package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7300321/how-to-use-pythons-pip-to-download-and-keep-the-zipped-files-for-a-package)

Comment: Excellent that worked perfectly, thanks. Is there a command to check what the dependencies are for a certain package. For example if I don't already have pandas and all I want to do is check what it's dependencies are via the command line.