# Make pip download prefer to download source-distributions (not wheels)

Tags: python, pip

This question [explains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7300321/how-to-use-pythons-pip-to-download-and-keep-the-zipped-files-for-a-package) how to make pip download and save packages. If I follow this formula, Pip will download wheel (.whl) files if available.

```
(venv) [user@host glances]$ pip download -d wheelhouse -r build_requirements.txt
Collecting wheel (from -r build_requirements.txt (line 1))
  File was already downloaded /usr_data/tmp/glances/wheelhouse/wheel-0.29.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pex (from -r build_requirements.txt (line 2))
  File was already downloaded /usr_data/tmp/glances/wheelhouse/pex-1.1.18-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting requests (from -r build_requirements.txt (line 3))
  File was already downloaded /usr_data/tmp/glances/wheelhouse/requests-2.12.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pip (from -r build_requirements.txt (line 4))
  File was already downloaded /usr_data/tmp/glances/wheelhouse/pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting setuptools (from -r build_requirements.txt (line 5))
  File was already downloaded /usr_data/tmp/glances/wheelhouse/setuptools-32.3.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Successfully downloaded wheel pex requests pip setuptools
```

Every single file that it downloaded was a Wheel - but what if I want to get a different kind of file?

I actually want to download the sdist (.tar.gz) files in preference to .whl files? Is there a way to tell Pip what kinds of files I actually want it to get? So instead of getting a directory full of wheels I might want a bunch of tar.gz files.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to `pip install -h`:

> --no-use-wheel Do not Find and prefer wheel archives when searching indexes and find-links locations. DEPRECATED in favour of --no-binary.

And

> --no-binary Do not use binary packages. Can be supplied multiple times, and each time adds to the existing value. Accepts either :all: to disable all binary packages, :none: to empty the set, or one or more package

You may need to upgrade pip with `pip install -U pip` if your version is too old.

Answer (score 12):

use `pip download --no-binary=:all: -r requirements.txt`

According to the pip documentation:

**--no-binary:**

> Do not use binary packages. Can be supplied multiple times, and each
>   time adds to the existing value. Accepts either :all: to disable all
>   binary packages, :none: to empty the set, or one or more package names
>   with commas between them. Note that some packages are tricky to
>   compile and may fail to install when this option is used on them.

It worked for me!