# How can I use --prefer-binary with pip in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

In Python 2 I can install a set of packages via `pip` preferring binary packages over source packages (meaning: fallback to source if binary not found) with:

**(1)** `pip install --prefer-binary -r requirements.txt`

In Python 3 I can do this with:

**(2)** `pip3 install --only-binary=:all: -r requirements.txt`

But (1) is not *exactly* equal to (2) since the former says:

> Prefer binaries when installing; but if I don't find a binary option, then I'll go with source.

The latter says:

> I will fail if no binaries are found; don't even try from source.

So, from the docs it seems that one solution could be to just manually enter each package which should be considered for source installation - meaning: the "only-binary" flag can be provided multiple times on the command line and can thus handle special-cases like that (by emptying it out, or giving specific package names to the binary packages). This answer details, to some extent, that approach: [Make pip download prefer to download source-distributions (not wheels)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41504340/make-pip-download-prefer-to-download-source-distributions-not-wheels).

However, I have a large number of both types of packages so I need an automated way like the (1) approach.

**Question**: How can I get a similar automated behavior as (1) but in Python/pip 3?

**Solution**: Pip is not Python - upgrade pip to vs. 20.X and use `--prefer-binary`.

Comment: Actually, maybe this is just due to an outdated pip? If I upgrade to vs. 20 this might fix it?
https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/

Comment: python is not pip. It is not fundamentally different when using python 2 or python3. `prefer-binary` is still part of the pip command line api, as you can see [here](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#cmdoption-prefer-binary)

Comment: Thanks @FlyingTeller - I updated my answer with the solution too. I had connected the two too tight in my head - this was very helpful.

Comment: You can answer your own question.  Please add `upgrade pip to vs. 20.X and use --prefer-binary` as an answer

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Solution**: `upgrade pip to vs. 20.X and use --prefer-binary`

Answer (score 6):

now its feasible to configure that on `requirements.txt`

```
--prefer-binary

<packages>
....
```

https://github.com/pypa/pip/pull/7996