# Cannot install discord.py using pip

Tags: python, discord.py

I tried to install `discord.py` using:

```
pip install discord
```

I got this:

```
Collecting discord
  Using cached discord-2.3.2-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (381 bytes)
Collecting discord.py>=2.3.2 (from discord)
  Using cached discord.py-2.3.2-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (4.9 kB)
Collecting aiohttp<4,>=3.7.4 (from discord.py>=2.3.2->discord)
  Using cached aiohttp-3.9.1-cp312-cp312-win_amd64.whl.metadata (7.6 kB)
Collecting attrs>=17.3.0 (from aiohttp<4,>=3.7.4->discord.py>=2.3.2->discord)
  Using cached attrs-23.2.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (9.5 kB)
Collecting multidict<7.0,>=4.5 (from aiohttp<4,>=3.7.4->discord.py>=2.3.2->discord)
  Using cached multidict-6.0.4.tar.gz (51 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Installing backend dependencies ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Collecting yarl<2.0,>=1.0 (from aiohttp<4,>=3.7.4->discord.py>=2.3.2->discord)
  Using cached yarl-1.9.4-cp312-cp312-win_amd64.whl.metadata (32 kB)
Collecting frozenlist>=1.1.1 (from aiohttp<4,>=3.7.4->discord.py>=2.3.2->discord)
  Using cached frozenlist-1.4.1-cp312-cp312-win_amd64.whl.metadata (12 kB)
Collecting aiosignal>=1.1.2 (from aiohttp<4,>=3.7.4->discord.py>=2.3.2->discord)
  Using cached aiosignal-1.3.1-py3-none-any.whl (7.6 kB)
Collecting idna>=2.0 (from yarl<2.0,>=1.0->aiohttp<4,>=3.7.4->discord.py>=2.3.2->discord)
  Using cached idna-3.6-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (9.9 kB)
Using cached discord-2.3.2-py3-none-any.whl (1.1 kB)
Using cached discord.py-2.3.2-py3-none-any.whl (1.1 MB)
Using cached aiohttp-3.9.1-cp312-cp312-win_amd64.whl (362 kB)
Using cached attrs-23.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (60 kB)
Using cached frozenlist-1.4.1-cp312-cp312-win_amd64.whl (50 kB)
Using cached yarl-1.9.4-cp312-cp312-win_amd64.whl (76 kB)
Using cached idna-3.6-py3-none-any.whl (61 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: multidict
  Building wheel for multidict (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for multidict (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [74 lines of output]
      *********************
      * Accelerated build *
      *********************
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\multidict
      copying multidict\_abc.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\multidict
      copying multidict\_compat.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\multidict
      copying multidict\_multidict_base.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\multidict
      copying multidict\_multidict_py.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\multidict
      copying multidict\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\multidict
      running egg_info
      writing multidict.egg-info\PKG-INFO
      writing dependency_links to multidict.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
      writing top-level names to multidict.egg-info\top_level.txt
      reading manifest file 'multidict.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
      reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files found matching 'multidict\_multidict.html'
      warning: no previously-included files found matching 'multidict\*.so'
      warning: no previously-included files found matching 'multidict\*.pyd'
      warning: no previously-included files found matching 'multidict\*.pyd'
      no previously-included directories found matching 'docs\_build'
      adding license file 'LICENSE'
      writing manifest file 'multidict.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
      C:\Users\obedh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-hidvvvrm\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\build_py.py:207: _Warning: Package 'multidict._multilib' is absent from the `packages` configuration.
      !!

              ********************************************************************************
              ############################
              # Package would be ignored #
              ############################
              Python recognizes 'multidict._multilib' as an importable package[^1],
              but it is absent from setuptools' `packages` configuration.

              This leads to an ambiguous overall configuration. If you want to distribute this
              package, please make sure that 'multidict._multilib' is explicitly added
              to the `packages` configuration field.

              Alternatively, you can also rely on setuptools' discovery methods
              (for example by using `find_namespace_packages(...)`/`find_namespace:`
              instead of `find_packages(...)`/`find:`).

              You can read more about "package discovery" on setuptools documentation page:

              - https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/package_discovery.html

              If you don't want 'multidict._multilib' to be distributed and are
              already explicitly excluding 'multidict._multilib' via
              `find_namespace_packages(...)/find_namespace` or `find_packages(...)/find`,
              you can try to use `exclude_package_data`, or `include-package-data=False` in
              combination with a more fine grained `package-data` configuration.

              You can read more about "package data files" on setuptools documentation page:

              - https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/datafiles.html


              [^1]: For Python, any directory (with suitable naming) can be imported,
                    even if it does not contain any `.py` files.
                    On the other hand, currently there is no concept of package data
                    directory, all directories are treated like packages.
              ********************************************************************************

      !!
        check.warn(importable)
      copying multidict\__init__.pyi -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\multidict
      copying multidict\py.typed -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\multidict
      running build_ext
      building 'multidict._multidict' extension
      error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for multidict
Failed to build multidict
ERROR: Could not build wheels for multidict, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I then tried to run a piece of code that came from a tutorial which involved `import discord`. The code itself is veeery long, so I won't include it here.

When I try to run it, (using `py bot.py` ) I find that

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\akjn\Desktop\Discordpy\bot.py", line 2, in <module>
    import discord
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'discord'
```

I would like to know if I am installing `discord.py` incorrectly and that is the problem, or otherwise how to make the code run correctly.

Comment: Looks like you may be using an older version of `pip` or have it set to prefer building from source. (See [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61734206/how-can-i-use-prefer-binary-with-pip-in-python-3)) The issue is that pip is failing to build `multidict` (`error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required.`). `multidict` has a number of pre-built wheels, so (for the easiest path) those should be used instead.

Comment: I'm using pip 23.3.2 by the way.

Comment: So... What happens when you use `--prefer-binary` or `--only-binary=:all:` as in the Q&A I'd linked?

Comment: Using `--prefer-binary` I got the same error.

Comment: With `--only-binary=:all:` I got:
```ERROR: Cannot install discord.py because these package versions have conflicting dependencies.

The conflict is caused by:
    aiohttp 3.9.1 depends on multidict<7.0 and >=4.5
    aiohttp 3.9.0 depends on multidict<7.0 and >=4.5

To fix this you could try to:
1. loosen the range of package versions you've specified
2. remove package versions to allow pip attempt to solve the dependency conflict

ERROR: ResolutionImpossible: for help visit https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/topics/dependency-resolution/#dealing-with-dependency-conflicts```

Comment: That'd odd. The current version of `multidict` is 6.0.4, which falls in the version range `aiohttp` wants. Are you able to install `multidict` on its own? Which version do you end up with? (`pip install --only-binary=:all: multidict`, the response should include something like `Successfully installed multidict-6.0.4`.)

Comment: @Obed, why not just `pip uninstall multidict` `pip uninstall discord.py` `pip install discord.py`? Reinstalling/upgrading/downgrading has always been the easiest way for me unless it was something related to how the interpreter was configured in my IDE.

Comment: I'm not sure what you meant @TheAmateurCoder. When I tried to uninstall discord.py, it told me that it was not installed already so there was no point. Then, when I installed it again, same issue.