# Install pyinstaller with no internet access

Tags: python, pip, pyinstaller

I'm trying to install pyinstaller on a windows 7 machine with no internet access at all. I've been following the [manual](http://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/) as much as I can but I'm totally new to python, pip and whatnot. I downloaded the archive for PyPI and unzipped it to my local drive. After installing PyPiWin32 I CD'd to the pyinstaller folder and ran `C:\python27\python setup.py install`. It seemed like everything was installing fine but then I got an error that pyinstaller was looking for the "future" package online, and of course couldn't find it...

So then I looked through the manual some more and tried running `pip pyinstaller install` which now gives me this error
`Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement future (from pyinstaller) (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for future (from pyinstaller)`

So what I assume went wrong (and I'm really not familiar with this) is that I tried an install, it missed some vital package because that was online, and now it is a bit confused. So is there a way to manually install the "future" package or am I just doing this totally wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at their [setup.py](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/blob/develop/setup.py#L28) file they append a separate [future](http://python-future.org/) package from PyPI, so you need to install that too before installing PyInstaller on Windows.

When in doubt, you can find a required package using this pattern:

```
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/<package>
```

and mostly (if not in all cases) it'll work just fine, therefore if you have a missing package `future`, just drop it into this url:

```
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/future
```

About the `future` package, it seems they require additional packages on Python 2.6, therefore you'll need `importlib` and `argparse` too judging from [future's setup.py](https://github.com/PythonCharmers/python-future/blob/master/setup.py#L90):

```
if sys.version_info[:2] == (2, 6):
    REQUIRES += ['importlib', 'argparse']
    TEST_REQUIRES += ['unittest2']
```

And just a note for installing, it's easier to navigate into a folder with a `setup.py` file and do:

```
pip install .
```

as it installs like it'd with `pip install <package>` therefore it'll be easier to uninstall a desired package.

In the end you'd do probably better to go for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7300321/5994041)'s solutions and download all required packages first with the same environment you want to target. Then you'll just point `pip` to the right folder, or install manually.