# Bundle all packages required from a Python script into a folder

Tags: python, python-3.x, package, bundle

I have my Python script and my requirements.txt ready.

What I want to do is to get all the packages listed in the "requirements.txt" into a folder. In the bundle, I'd for example have the full packages of "pymysql", "bs4" as well as all their dependencies.

I have absolutely no idea how to do this. Could you help me please? I am stuck and I am really struggling with this.

I am using Python 3.6

I am using "pip download -r requirements.txt" but it's not downloading the dependencies and outputs me only.whl files whereas I'm looking for "proper" folders..

Comment: You have several options. You can use conda and export an environment which contains everything. Or you can have pip do this. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/7300619/6522112

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use Python's pip to download and keep the zipped files for a package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7300321/how-to-use-pythons-pip-to-download-and-keep-the-zipped-files-for-a-package)

Comment: Thank you. I'm using pip download but I'm having .whl files now. How can I have proper folders?

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just use a virtual environment (virtualenv folder_name) and then activate it unless you are looking for something else.

Once it's activated install of your libraries and drown its there using pip install