# What is the best way to create a script file for creating .zip files?

Tags: python, linux, macos, operating-system, zip

There are several commands. Each of these commands performs certain actions. I want to combine all these commands into a single script file. After running this script, I want to get a `.zip` file at the output in the specified directory. What is the best way to create this script to work on Linux and macOS operating systems? Which is better to use `.sh`, `Makefile`, or something else?

For example, the `pip install cassandra-driver` command installs a third-party package in my virtual environment? I can install this third-party package in a specific directory on my operating system using the `--target` command. Is it possible to immediately wrap this downloadable package in a `.zip` file? Plus you need to add a file to this `.zip` file `config.py` file.

**macOS**:

```
mkdir /src/dependencies/cassandra-driver
pip install cassandra-driver --targer /src/dependencies/cassandra-driver
zip -r cassandra-driver.zip /src/dependencies/cassandra-driver /src/config.py
```

Comment: It's not clear... what are the expected contents of this zip file? For pip, instead of install, you can just [download the package without installing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7300321/2745495) or use `wget` (or similar) to download it direct from PyPi. As for "best way", that would lead to opinion-based answers, which are off-topic here. Are you asking for a cross-platform shell script? Something that will run on both Linux and mac? What's wrong with those 3 lines you have now? It seems straightforward to put those 3 lines in a script, but then you mentioned Makefile, and it got confusing.

Comment: ...or are you asking for a script that will work for any Python package? How about if the environment has no `pip` available?

Comment: In short, I need this to archive packages for `AWS Lambda Layers`. I want to understand how to optimize commands. To be more precise, combine the second and third commands. As I asked in the post, is it possible to immediately wrap this downloadable package in a `.zip` file? I don't want to store this third-party package. Also, my third command raises such error: `zip error: Nothing to do! (try: zip -r cassandra-driver.zip . -i /src/config.py)`. I tried to use this command in the error message but it returns an empty `.zip` file. Do you have any ideas? `.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a bash script and have it executed on *nix.

Use arguments to specify what package should be zipped to what location and what config should be added.

```
#!/bin/bash

packageName=$1
destinationPath=$2
configLocation=$3

mkdir /tmp/$packageName
pip download $packageName -d /tmp/$packageName
zip -r $destinationPath/$packageName.zip /tmp/$packageName/* $configLocation
rm -rf /tmp/$packageName
```

Use with:

`bash /path/scriptName.sh cassandra-driver /src/dependencies/ /src/config.py`

with `scriptName.sh` being this script,

`cassandra-driver` the name of the package,

`/src/dependencies/` the path where you want to store the `.zip`,

`/src/config.py` full path of file you want to append to the archive.

EDIT: It now downloads the package as .zip without installing it.

Comment: Is it possible to combine the second and third lines of your script? After archiving, I don't need a third-party package. You will have to write an additional command to delete it. Isn't it?

Comment: You want to delete the downloaded package, because you now have the zip?

Comment: Yes, you are right. As I asked in the post, is it possible to immediately wrap this downloadable package in a `.zip` file? I don't want to store this third-party package.

Comment: Can I specify the output directory where to put the zip file in the third line of the script?

Comment: See my edit. It now doesn't install the package but downloads a .zip right away.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried to test your new code but it raises an error: `no such option: --target`. Also, the script raises such error: `zip error: Nothing to do! (try: zip -r cassandra-driver.zip . -i /src/config.py)`. I tried to use this command in the error message but it returns an empty `.zip` file. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Yes, `--target` doesn't work for `download`. I edited the answer again.

Comment: Have you tested your script? It downloads a third-party package to the specified directory but does not archive it or delete it after downloading. What could be the reason for the error that I described to you in the previous comment? The third command doesn't work if you run it through a script. Very strange.

Comment: Try again. If it doesn't work for you we can discuss it via chat.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222589/discussion-between-nurzhan-nogerbek-and-anonjnr).